# What is then, thenEmpty, thenMany and flatMapMany in spring webflux?

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I don't understand the use and the difference between then, `thenEmpty`, `thenMany` and `flatMapMany` on `Flux` or `Mono` in spring webflux.

Comment: I found the answer in project reactor documentation

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

Comment: Funny how this "question" got 30 upvotes, without actually being a question :) 1+

Answer (score 79, accepted):

- **`flatMap` vs `flatMapMany`**

In functional programming, `flatMap` returns the same type than the type that bear the method, so for `Mono<T>`, `flatMap` returns a `Mono`. Which means that only one element can be emitted by the inner `Publisher` (or that it is truncated). We enforced that by having `Mono#flatMap` take a `Function<T, Mono<R>>`.

As a consequence, we needed an alternative for more arbitrary `Publisher` that could emit more than one element. Hence `Mono#flatMapMany(Function<T, Publisher<R>>)` which returns a `Flux<R>`.

TL;DR: `Mono#flatMap` is for **asynchronous** but **1-to-1** transformation of the element in the source `Mono`, `Mono#flatMapMany` is for **1-to-N asynchronous** transformation (like Flux#flatMap).

- **`then`, `thenEmpty` and `thenMany`**

All the `thenXXX` methods on `Mono` have one semantic in common: they ignore the source `onNext` signals and react on completion signals (`onComplete` and `onError`), continuing the sequence at this point with various options. As a consequence, this can change the generic type of the returned `Mono`:

1. `then` will just replay the source terminal signal, resulting in a `Mono<Void>` to indicate that this never signals any `onNext`.
2. `thenEmpty` not only returns a `Mono<Void>`, but it takes a `Mono<Void>` as a parameter. It represents a concatenation of the source completion signal *then* the second, *empty* Mono completion signal. In other words, it completes when A then B have both completed sequentially, and doesn't emit data.
3. `thenMany` waits for the source to complete then plays all the signals from its `Publisher<R>` parameter, resulting in a `Flux<R>` that will "pause" until the source completes, *then* emit the *many* elements from the provided publisher before replaying its completion signal as well.

Comment: I'm using `thenMany` to continue after a guard. Is it a good pattern? I.e. the guard returns `Mono.error(...)` if precondition failed, `Mono.empty()` otherwise. Then I have `thenMany` to continue the computation and return `Flux` in my webflux app.

Comment: yes that should work @wilmol, although I imagine the `Mono.error` is used inside a `flatMap` (that you called a "guard")? in which case it would be less overhead to directly return the `Flux` in the else branch of the flatmap rather than from the thenMany

Comment: Note that all of the ``then`` Mono's will be subscribed althougth any of then throw an error, while ``map``'s won't

Comment: https://intojava.wordpress.com/2020/11/25/difference-between-flatmap-and-flatmapmany-in-webflux/

Answer (score 1):

In Spring WebFlux with Flux or Mono:

then: Executes an operation and continues when the previous operation completes, without returning any value.
thenEmpty: Performs an action and returns an empty Mono/Flux.
thenMany: Executes an operation and continues with the given Flux sequence.
flatMapMany: Projects each element emitted by the source Mono/Flux into a Publisher, allowing asynchronous operations and merging of results into a single Flux.
Essentially:

then is for continuation without returning a value.
thenEmpty is for executing an action and returning an empty Mono/Flux.
thenMany continues with a new Flux sequence.
flatMapMany transforms elements into Publishers, allowing asynchronous processing and merging the results into a single Flux stream.